# Помогите с простой регуляркой (содержимое атрибута тега)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Привет, есть регулярка, получает все теги <td></td>

```
/<td.*?>.*?<\/td.*?>/si
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить: `содержимое атрибута class у всех тегов <td></td>`

PS> Предполагаю что закрывающийся тег даже не нужен, тк не может содержать атрибутов.

фиддл тут: http://ideone.com/gN6Kb2

Comment: Ы, опять... [Читать до просветления](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: ну зачем сразу, в моём случае разметка всегда едина и корректна, я конечно сделал вычисление позиции вторых '"' (str_pos) - вычисление позиции первых '"', получаю более чем верный результат, но это костыль, а мне бы хотелось preg_match_all и я знаю он есть ;)

Comment: А воспользовались бы нормальным парсером - результат был бы сразу, не пришлось бы тратить время на поболтать здесь, и гонять лишние байтики по интернетам. Что объективным образом показывает, какой подход кривой, а какой - верный.

Comment: Моя совесть не может мне позволить подключить целый парсер (sipmple_html_dom) когда это можно заменить одной строчкой...

Comment: Я тоже когда-то думал. Но давно уже устал для каждой мелкой задачи изобретать персональный костыль. Мне проще даже в однострочник вписать `use HTML::Tree` и гарантированно получить результат, чем тратить время на решение простейших задач. Чего и всем желаю :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635849/can-simplexml-be-used-to-rifle-through-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так.

```
"/<td class=[\'|\"](.*)?[\'|\"]>.*?<\/td>/"
```

Вот:

```
$reg = "/<td class=[\'|\"](.*)?[\'|\"]>.*?<\/td>/";
$html = <<<HTML
    <td>freefreefreefree</td>
    <td id="myid">ididididid</td>
    <td class="myclass">dgfbfdf</td>
    <td class="notmyclass">dgfbfdf</td>
HTML;

preg_match_all($reg,$html,$out);
echo $out[1][0]; //myclass
```

Comment: `
$reg= "/<td class=['|\"](.*)['|\"]?>.*?</td>/";
preg_match_all($reg, $html, $out);
`
.


` Warning: preg_match_all() [<a href='function.preg-match-all'>function.preg-match-all</a>]: Unknown modifier 't' in C:\wamp\www\bux\index.php on line 11`

Comment: Последний `/` не экранирован же: `<\/td>`.

Comment: Поправил. Там и скобки небыли экранированы )

Comment: К сожалению неверно:  Warning: preg_match_all() [<a href='function.preg-match-all'>function.preg-match-all</a>]: Unknown modifier '.' in C:\wamp\www\bux\index.php on line 11

Comment: Ворчливо: ещё один аргумент за парсер: очевидно, что нужно не слепо копировать регексп из ответа, а добавить в него ограничители. И если такие пробелы в понимании регекспов, то точно нужен другой инструмент...

Comment: Появилась безумная идея сделать генератор регулярных выражений из css селекторов. Кто-нибудь слышал о таком ? Я не нашел в интернете, а велосипедить не хочется.

Comment: У меня все получилось. Дополнил рабочим примером(сверху)

Comment: @ReinRaus он не нужен :) им ведь обычно не сам элемент нужен, а то аттрибут, то содержимое то содержимое обрезанное как нить, короче, никакую практическую задачу такой генератор не решит. да и писать валидный замучаешься, на вскидку -  скажем в html по середине встречается такой вот валидный код: 

    <div>     
    <a data-open-tag="<div>">aaa</a> 
    </div>
    <a data-close-tag="</div>">aaa</a>

и мы хотим PCRE regexp для получения элемента `<div>`, конечно можно, но какой ценой...

Comment: @eicto, такой код не валиден :) это все решаемо, я уже писал выражения, которые способны учитывать спецификацию хтмл, вот только делал узко нацеленные выражения.

Comment: почему это не валиден ?

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>   
    <a data-open-tag="<div>">aaa</a> 
    </div>
    <a data-close-tag="</div>">aaa</a>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: По спецификации должны быть &lt; &gt; хотя html5 не читал- может и можно так писать

Comment: да ?

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> --><!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> --><!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> --><html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>   
    <input type=text value="<div>">
    </div>
    <p>
    <input type=text value="</div>">
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: Забавно. Валидацию проходит, а в спецификации написано, что надо эскейпить. Здесь причина по которой я вообще решился читать спецификацию:  
http://hashcode.ru/questions/189556/

Comment: @ReinRaus да в любом случае будет миллион граблей, да и гарантировать что все html вылидны нельзя... как насчет 

    <!-- </div> --> 

?

Comment: Даже больше, такое тоже прекрасно проходит валидацию:


`<p>< div > </ div > < /div ></p>`

И, ЕМНИП, в этом случае стандарт явно разрешает угловые скобки. Но могу ошибаться, надо поискать.