# (php) Обратиться к атрибуту переменной

Tags: php, html

Всем привет. Есть у меня переменная `$image` которая содержит в себе код:

```
<img width="450" height="338" src="bla-bla.png" class="attachment-shop_single wp-post-image" alt="Brioche_4734">
```

Хочу обратиться к атрибуту `src`, пробую и так, и так

```
echo $image['src'];
var_dump($image['src']);
```

но выводит или boolean:false или null

Comment: Надо либо парсить строку регуляркой, либо работать через [DOM](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.dom.php)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильный парсинг значения Href с внутренней ссылкой](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/317299/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-href-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: Если интересует регулярка, то пример работы можно посмотреть в этом [ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/280768/5079)

Comment: @BOPOH нет, не дубликат. Мне не понятно как это можно адаптировать для моего примера - что я буду загружать через  $DOM->loadXML("..");'

Comment: Это именно дубликат, я вам привел два примера где решаются аналогичные задачи, ваша от них ничем существенно не отличается. Если вам что-то не понятно в решении, вы можете задать дополнительный вопрос, в котором можете попросить уточнения каких-либо деталей.

Comment: @BOPOH я же и уточняю в комменте выше "что я буду загружать через $DOM->loadXML("..");'" ?

Comment: В том ответе в `loadXML` вставляете переменную `$image`, меняете в коде ответа тег `a` на `img`, меняете `href` на `src` и смотрите результат. Дубликат не потому что вопрос один-в-один совпадает, а потому что ответ может быть использован и для решения вашей задачи